# How we can create list with unique permission?

Tags: list, permissions, sharepoint-server

There is requirement to create a list by using some already available list template with unique permission. But when i am creating any list, by default all the user permissions are getting inherited then i have to click "stop inheritance" option and then remove all the users from permission list.

Can we create a list with unique permission such that there is no user in permission list?

Thanks.

Comment: You can stop inheritance programmatically and then remove the permissions & assign permissions which you need. If you need code for this then I can provide you.

Comment: It means it is not possible with OOB feature.Please provide me the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stop inheritance & remove all permissions on the list and assign the permission to User on List :

```
SPList list = web.Lists["myList"];

list.BreakRoleInheritance(false,false); // break inheritance & remove parent permissions

// Now assign permission to "user1"
SPUser spUser = web.EnsureUser("user1");  
SPRoleAssignment roleAssignment = new SPRoleAssignment(spUser);  
SPRoleDefinition roleDefinition = new SPRoleDefinition();

roleDefinition = web.RoleDefinitions.GetByType(SPRoleType.Reader); // Give Permission to User on this List

SPRoleDefinitionBindingCollection roleDefinitionBindingCollection = new SPRoleDefinitionBindingCollection();
roleDefinitionBindingCollection.Add(roleDefinition);
roleAssignment.ImportRoleDefinitionBindings(roleDefinitionBindingCollection);
list.RoleAssignments.Add(roleAssignment);
list.Update();
```

Now, only 'user1' have permission on the list.